# Xcode FIREBASE crashes

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have recently upgraded to Swift 4.2 and I am not able to run my project anymore since then.
I had hundreds of mistakes which I all fixed, the app starts but crashes as soon as it tries to access data from my database

example code

```
            guard let currentUser = API.User.CURRENT_USER?.uid else {return}
```

crash: Thread 1: signal SIGABRT

I had my app working for over a year now and thousands of users so the code worked previously quit fine.
I have updated my cocoa pods to the newest point, as my terminal said that firebaseauth requires at least 1.4 cocoa pods.
I have updated and newly installed all pods, I deleted my plist and downloaded it again and put it into the project, all to no avail.
My app is working if you download the old version from the App Store, but I want to update some things and need it to run again
Any advice? I have tried everything I found

Comment: Check `API.User` - is it nil?

Answer (score 0):

For Firebase 4/5 and Swift 4, here's the function call to get the currently authenticated users uid

```
guard let currentUser = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
```